# Computing Jaccard Similarity between DataFrame Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, loops

Here's what my dataset looks like:
[image: dataset about comorbidities]

I want to iterate over columns to compute [Jaccard similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index). I am not interested in using libraries to do it btw.

Here's my code:

```
def jaccard_binary(x,y):
    """A function for finding the similarity between two binary vectors"""
    intersection = np.logical_and(x, y)
    union = np.logical_or(x, y)
    similarity = intersection.sum() / float(union.sum())
    return similarity


for (columns) in df.items():
    jb = jaccard_binary(i, j)
    jac_sim = pd.DataFrame(jb, index=df.columns, columns=df.columns)
print(jac_sim)
```

But of course something is wrong because it shows me the same value for all the data:
[image: the values the code is showing]

What am I doing wrong? I want to do this that way because I will later need to iterate over columns to do some other formula to calculate other things. That's why I need to iterate over data but I have no idea how to do it right.

Here's also what I tried but it gives "1" value for everything:

```
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    for j in range(0,len(df.columns)):
        jb = jaccard_binary(i, j)
        jac_sim = pd.DataFrame(jb, index=df.columns, columns=df.columns)
    print(jb)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you specify what you want to put into the jaccard function? You want to calculate PAIRWISE(?!) Jaccard distances between all rows, right?

Comment: ...right, I think so? Just wanted to calculate Jaccard similarity between rows/columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @J_H's anwser, some code is added to show how jaccard similarity can be calculated for many rows and columns

```
import pandas as pd


def jaccard_similarity(
    a: pd.Series,
    b: pd.Series,
):
    assert len(a) == len(b)  # should be a pair of columns from same dataframe
    total_size = len(a) + len(b)
    intersection = (a == b).sum()
    return intersection / (total_size - intersection)


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "patient": ["P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5"],
        "cancer":  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        "thyroid": [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        "allergy": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    }
)

# pairwise jaccard distance for rows
for row_index_1, row1 in df.iterrows():
    for row_index_2, row2 in df.iterrows():
        print(jaccard_similarity(row1, row2))

# pairwise jaccard distance for columns
for col1 in df:
    for col2 in df:
        print(jaccard_similarity(df[col1], df[col2]))
```

Comment: You are very welcome! If this was helpful, consider chosing J_H or my answer as the accepted answer :-)

Comment: Hi again! It's working but I have a hard time reshaping the data into matrix, any clues? :(

Comment: Maybe you can ask a new question with some data and explain how you want it to look like

Answer (score 1):

> ... iterate over columns to compute Jaccard similarity.

You wanted to use the equality operator rather than logical AND.

```
import unittest

import pandas as pd


class JaccardTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_jaccard(self):
        df = _get_example_data()
        self.assertAlmostEqual(4 / 6, jaccard_similarity(df.cancer, df.thyroid))
        self.assertAlmostEqual(3 / 7, jaccard_similarity(df.cancer, df.allergy))


def jaccard_similarity(
    a: pd.Series,
    b: pd.Series,
):
    assert len(a) == len(b)  # should be a pair of columns from same dataframe
    total_size = len(a) + len(b)
    intersection = (a == b).sum()
    return intersection / (total_size - intersection)


def _get_example_data() -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "patient": ["P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5"],
            "cancer":  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            "thyroid": [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            "allergy": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        }
    )
```

Example data:

```
  patient  cancer  thyroid  allergy
0      P1       1        1        0
1      P2       1        0        0
2      P3       0        0        0
3      P4       0        0        0
4      P5       0        0        0
```

In this example the equality operator gives
us a vector of five booleans.
We then just plug the figures into the definition.

This computes symptom similarity, as you requested.
Clearly one could compare similarity of
patients to, say, P1, if there was some alternate requirement.
Take the transpose `df.T`, or operate on rows.

Comment: Thank you but what if I have larger datasets? Writing everything out won't work then or am I understanding something wrong?

Comment: I can't see all your data. You neglected to offer a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I wrote one for you. The `jaccard_similarity()` function works for any pair of boolean Series. Clearly the details of how you get example data is going to vary according to whether you read from this or that .CSV or maybe from a database table.

Comment: I read data from .CSV file and it's kinda larger than I have showed, sorry!

Comment: I'm not sure what "kinda larger" means for this problem. Bigger than available RAM? I used the pandas library because that's what appeared in the OP. Typically I prefer `import polars` for large datasets because it conserves memory relative to pandas. Solution would be much the same, though, as they have compatible APIs that are layered atop numpy.